# Unable to create PDF from JSPDF

Tags: vue.js, jspdf

Save in DB and import data and create a pdf file using jspdf.
Data is stored up to html tag...

```
select ct_contents from contract where ct_id = 659;
RESULT : `<p style="text-align:justify"><span style="font-size:10.5pt"><span style="font-family:Century,serif"><span style="font-family:&quot;MS Mincho&quot;">氏　　名</span></span></span></p>`
```

I have this js code :

```
let pdfName = this.newTemplate.tp_title.trim()
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.addFileToVFS('NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.ttf', VFS);
doc.addFont('NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.ttf', 'NotoSansCJKjp', 'Bold');
doc.setFont('NotoSansCJKjp', 'Bold');
doc.setFontSize(12);
var paragraph = this.contract.ct_contents;
var lines = doc.splitTextToSize(paragraph, 150);
doc.text(15, 60, lines);
doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf');
```

add a font to work on it, but check the downloaded pdf, the html tag will also appear.
I want to remove this tag and make it appear only in text.

image is the result of downloading by pdf.

[image]

And it is page 3 in ms word and only page 1 of pdf is download.....
How can I get the font to come out without getting the html tag?